# gbash 'git rm' multiple files that are found by a 'find' command

Tags: bash, shell

I want to 'git rm' a bunch of files that are found by a 'find' command. The files should have a certain suffix. I got this:

```
TEST_PATH='/usr/src'

function main() {
    for i in "$@"
    do
        echo "current i  = ${i}"
        COMMAND='find $TEST_PATH -maxdepth 20 -name '*_${i}.txt' -exec git rm {} \;'
        # COMMAND="$(find $TEST_PATH -maxdepth 20 name '*_${i}.txt' -print0 | xargs -0 -I{} cp {} .)"
        # COMMAND="find $TEST_PATH -maxdepth 20 -name '*_${i}.txt' -exec cp {} . \;"
        #   COMMAND="find . '*.BUILD' | while read file; do echo "$file"; done \;"
    done

  echo "Running Command: $COMMAND"
  $COMMAND
}

gbash::main "$@"
```

Running it will throw an error like this:

```
$ sh abc.sh 123
current i  = 123
Running Command: find ../../src/python/servers/innertube/tests/ -maxdepth 20 -name "*_9421870.txt" -exec rm {}\;
find: missing argument to `-exec'
```

I've read and tried all the solutions on stackoverflow (see the commented out code) but none works...

Comment: Why are you storing the command in a variable? [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050). Just execute it normally and debug writing something like `echo git rm {} \;`.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

The problem is that you should `eval` contents of the variable containing command:

```
eval $COMMAND
```

From `man eval`:

> The  eval utility shall construct a command by concatenating arguments together, separating each with a `<space>` character.  The constructed command shall be read and executed by the shell.

**Original answer**

Replace `{}\;` with `{} \;` or `{} +`.

Read the man page for `find`. The action used in your command is documented as:

> `-exec command ;`
>
> Execute command; true if 0 status is returned.  All following  arguments  > to  find are  taken  to  be arguments to the command until an argument consisting of `;` is encountered.  The string `{}` is replaced by the current file name being processed everywhere  it occurs in the arguments to the command...

So the command failed because the `{}\;` sequence is interpreted as `command`.

Comment: @BenjaminW., I'm sure he hasn't. Besides, I see this string in his post: `Running Command: find ../../src/python/servers/innertube/tests/ -maxdepth 20 -name "*_9421870.txt" -exec rm {}\;` . And I don't see spaces between `{}` and `\;` here. He may be actually running different script than that in the question.

Comment: @BenjaminW., you're right. The problem was that he run command as `$COMMAND` instead of `eval $COMMAND`.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Seems like `'-exec git rm {} +'` works but `'-exec git rm {} \;'` does not. So the final version for COMMAND is :

    `COMMAND="find $TEST_PATH -maxdepth 20 -name \"*_${i}*.txt\" -exec git rm {} +"`

And yes, we need add eval:

    `eval "$COMMAND"`